# Why don't I have any friends?

Tags: tiny-tower

In *Tiny Tower*, you have the option of viewing your friend's tower, giving them gifts from your own stocks, and... That's pretty much it, I think.

The problem is, **I have no friends.**

**How do I get friends in *Tiny Tower*?**

Comment: Meet new people and be nice to them. Offer to do things with them like seeing a movie or going out for a meal or drinks. After spending time with them remember to keep talking to them so that you don't drift apart. Oh and make sure they have an IPhone to play Tiny Tower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are playing on iOS, you get friends by adding them to your Game Center account - any friends you have there that are also playing Tiny Tower will show up as your Tiny Tower friends, and you can then visit them and gift them things.

To add a friend to Game Center, you need to sign into the Game Center app with your Apple ID, and then there is a button labelled "friends". Tap that, then tap "add friends", and then you can either add friends using their Game Center username, or their email.

You cannot add friends from within the Tiny Tower app itself.

Comment: What about android? Can you have friends cross platforms? (in TT )

Comment: @Foxtrot I don't know how to add friends on Android, but I do know that you cannot go cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Friends can be added via GameCenter.